# Does anyone know how to retrieve list of cell cycle genes from KEGG in R?

Tags: r, package, cell

I know how to retrieve a list of genes for specific pathways from KEGG website by using KEGG API but I couldn't find any packages that could do the same thing in R.
The only annotation package I found was KEGG.db which just give a list of available pathways in KEGG.

```
http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/docs/keggapi.html
```

by entering the pathway ID and search it on KEGG like this one for cell cycle genes:

```
http://rest.kegg.jp/get/hsa04110
```

Does anybody know any package in R/solution that could help me out with my problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you have a look on bioconductor? A quick research gave me several hits, e.g. [KEGG.db](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/annotation/html/KEGG.db.html), but also [KEGGgraph](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/KEGGgraph.html) or [KEGGprofile](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/KEGGprofile.html) and some others. I think a bit more details would help to understand what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rereading your question, I believe this the R package that can help you. It is on bioconductor and allows you to interact through R and REST with KEGG.

[KEGGREST](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/KEGGREST.html)

> KEGGREST: Client-side REST access to KEGG
>
> A package that provides a client interface to the KEGG REST server. Based on KEGGSOAP by J. Zhang, R. Gentleman, and Marc Carlson, and KEGG (python package) by Aurelien Mazurie.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found two ways to get the KEGG pathways and their genes (one of them uses the previous proposed package `KEGGREST`).

**FIRST WAY**

```
library(limma)
library(AnnotationDbi)
library(org.Hs.eg.db)

# We get entrez ids and their pathways.
gene_pathways <- getGeneKEGGLinks(species="hsa")

# This is to get the gene symbols using entrez ids
gene_pathways$Symbol <- mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, gene_pathways$GeneID,
                       column="SYMBOL", keytype="ENTREZID")

# pathway names
pathway_names <- getKEGGPathwayNames(species="hsa")


KEGG_pathways <- merge(gene_pathways, pathway_names, by="PathwayID")
```

Output:

```
head(KEGG_pathways)

PathwayID GeneID Symbol Description

1 path:hsa00010  10327 AKR1A1 Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)

2 path:hsa00010    124  ADH1A Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)

3 path:hsa00010    125  ADH1B Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)

4 path:hsa00010    126  ADH1C Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)

5 path:hsa00010    127   ADH4 Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)
```

**SECOND WAY**

```
library(KEGGREST)
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
library(tidyverse)

# get pathways and their entrez gene ids

hsa_path_entrez  <- keggLink("pathway", "hsa") %>% 
  tibble(pathway = ., eg = sub("hsa:", "", names(.)))

# get gene symbols and ensembl ids using entrez gene ids

hsa_kegg_anno <- hsa_path_entrez %>%
  mutate(
    symbol = mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, eg, "SYMBOL", "ENTREZID"),
    ensembl = mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, eg, "ENSEMBL", "ENTREZID")
  )

# Pathway names
hsa_pathways <- keggList("pathway", "hsa") %>% 
  tibble(pathway = names(.), description = .)

KEGG_pathways <- left_join(hsa_kegg_anno, hsa_pathways)
```

Output:

```
head(KEGG_pathways)

A tibble: 6 x 5

pathway       eg    symbol ensembl         description                                        
<chr>         <chr> <chr>  <chr>           <chr>    
                                          
1 path:hsa00010 10327 AKR1A1 ENSG00000117448 Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)

2 path:hsa00010 124   ADH1A  ENSG00000187758 Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)

3 path:hsa00010 125   ADH1B  ENSG00000196616 Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)

4 path:hsa00010 126   ADH1C  ENSG00000248144 Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)

5 path:hsa00010 127   ADH4   ENSG00000198099 Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis - Homo sapiens (human)
```

If for some reason you need to query other species you just have to replace "hsa". With this line of code `keggList("organism")` you can get the list of available species.

```
org <- keggList("organism")

head(org)

T.number organism species phylogeny                               
[1,] "T01001" "hsa"    "Homo sapiens (human)"                                "Eukaryotes;Animals;Vertebrates;Mammals"

[2,] "T01005" "ptr"    "Pan troglodytes (chimpanzee)"                        "Eukaryotes;Animals;Vertebrates;Mammals"

[3,] "T02283" "pps"    "Pan paniscus (bonobo)"                               "Eukaryotes;Animals;Vertebrates;Mammals"

[4,] "T02442" "ggo"    "Gorilla gorilla gorilla (western lowland gorilla)"   "Eukaryotes;Animals;Vertebrates;Mammals"

[5,] "T01416" "pon"    "Pongo abelii (Sumatran orangutan)"                   "Eukaryotes;Animals;Vertebrates;Mammals"
```

NOTE:
Although I have used `org.Hs.eg.db` to get the gene symbols, it is also possible to get them from `biomaRt`.

```
library(biomaRt)
mart <- useDataset("hsapiens_gene_ensembl", useMart("ensembl"))
attributes <- listAttributes(mart)
genes <- getBM(attributes = c("hgnc_symbol", "entrezgene_id"),
               mart = mart)
```

Additional useful info about `KEGGREST` can be found in the [vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/KEGGREST/inst/doc/KEGGREST-vignette.html).